# How to parse a midlet JAD file in C#?

Tags: c#, midlet

Besides doing it manually using regular expression search, is there other better ways to parse a JAD file?

I need to be able to search for and replace/insert a new `MIdlet-Install-Notify` property to a JAD file given, also updating the value of the `MIDlet-Jar-URL` property.

Using ANTLR or TinyPG is a bit overkill for my case.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even Regex might be overkill, although it certainly will get the job done.  It is a very simple text format to parse, string.StartsWith() and string.IndexOf() to find the colon would work well.

Comment: I ended up streamreading the jad into a dictionary, still a bit overkill but that offers me the uniqueness key checking, the downside is that when i change a value of a given key, I have to do the remove() followed by an add().

Thanks anyway.